# Disable configuration key by default in AX 2012

Tags: configuration, default, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to keep some custom created configuration keys to be disabled (unchecked) by default. However, its behaviour can be changed by user after that.

By default, it shows those conf keys checked or enabled. I want them to be disabled by default. Please let me know how to do so

Answer (score 0):

you can uncheck the custom key and then **do database sync**

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is to keep particular configuration key disabled (unchecked) by default unless user checks it